# What part in the OPC captures json response from the step functions?

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, prototype-js

For example the `saveBillingAction()` function when you click *next*, an ajax call is made to `/checkout/onepage/saveBilling/`

*What captures this json output?*

I created a sidebar with cart data and want to update the shipping cost based on whether or not the user has a shipping cost.

Answer (score 2):

When `saveBillingAction()` call the `json capture` the layout `handler and generate html from layout`

Just goto `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController`  and check at `saveBillingAction` function and on the function,you can see there basic of logic it `creating next steps html` using call of function   `_getPaymentMethodsHtml()` and `_getShippingMethodsHtml`.

On both of this functions.You  can see that `pragmatically call layout` and a handler `checkout_onepage_shippingmethod` and then generate xml `generateXml`() and  generate block `generateBlocks` and a html out has been creted,

You can see:

```
 protected function _getShippingMethodsHtml()
    {
        $layout = $this->getLayout();
        $update = $layout->getUpdate();
        $update->load('checkout_onepage_shippingmethod');
        $layout->generateXml();
        $layout->generateBlocks();
        $output = $layout->getOutput();
        return $output;
    }
```

also you can get  handler on  checkut.xml file and here defining  blocks;

```
<checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_available" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml"/>
    </checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>
```

for case of function `_getShippingMethodsHtml()` next step shipping method has been rendered to json.